# How to store multiple values under the same field on Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Trying to create a like button plus counter on my app. Each card on my app has a specific sale_id number that I'm passing into my component. On Firestore, I'm storing this sale_id:

```
 const addLikeDocument = async (like: string) => [
    await db.collection('likes').doc(currentUser.actor).set({ like, sale_id }),
  ];
```

I then display the likes next to the like button using this const

```
const likedComment =
    likes?.docs?.filter((doc) => doc.data().like === 'yes').length &&
    likes?.docs?.filter((doc) => doc.data().sale_id === sale_id).length;
```

the problem is that what this is doing is that it replaces the sale ID with whichever one I like. So if I like sale 12345, that one has a number 1 next to it, but if I like sale 54321, that one gets the like and the other goes back to 0. So I'm trying to store multiple values under sale_id on firebase if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep an array of sales IDs, you can do:

```
set({ 
  like, 
  sale_id: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(sale_id) 
}),
```

The `arrayUnion` operator add the `sale_id` value to the array if it's not already in there. Also see the Firestore documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: this does seem like a solution but it didn't work for me.  In my case, when I click the "like" button, it stores the sale ID (passed in from an API fetch on another component). But when I click another one, it stores that one instead. Your solution added a "0" next my sale ID which I assume represents how many items there are. But no matter how many clicks, I just get a new sale ID and it remains at 0.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you tried, and a screenshot of a document in the Firebase console with the result?